# How to print PDF along with some text metadata of it on the same page?

Tags: pdf, printing, automation

I would like to print PDFs (Invoices received) along with the additional metadata corresponding to those PDFs(my purchase records) on a single page. I have tried MailMerge initially, but at maximum, it can only merge Images on a page.
The ideal solution to this problem shall end up taking up metadata (from DB), PDFs (from Drive or Cloud or DB) and put them in their corresponding placeholders in a single page, and output a PDF/Print. Needless to say, the PDFs need to be reduced by approximately 75% to make space for the metadata on the same page.

PS: I need to do this for at least 350 invoices.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are looking for a software recommendation, so you should post it on that site

Comment: @RohitGupta, not exactly, I was wondering if there's any way to do this without having any other extra software.

Comment: There is no software whatsoever mentioned in your question. So without making a software recommendation how is it possible to provide any assistance?

Comment: @Kayshav - it makes no sense that this functionality would exist, tailor made for you.

Comment: On what operating system? Mac, Windows, Linus, Sun... ? Using what application?

Comment: While you may not want software to do this, the basic PDF handlers don't support this, and so software will be needed. THAT SAID, TO THE SOFTWARE REC CLOSE VOTERS OP didn't ask for a software rec and so their question is NOT a software rec AND we CAN recommend software if it solves the problem.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Windows 10. Ideally I would want it to be integrated with Google Forms/Spreadsheet (DB input source) and produce the output through a text editor like GoogleDocs or LibreOffice, etc.  Also, I am fairly surprised that there is no freeware (or even paid) for this job.

Comment: @music2myear yeah, I mean I am definitely clear on this that most PDF handlers don't have the option to automate putting corresponding custom-metadata on them. And yeah, I am looking for both software (if it solves to the point) or any extension/add on/solution/way around with existing GoogleDocs/LibreOffice. Thanks,

Comment: Sample output should look like: https://imgur.com/a/gLe6gyB

Comment: @Kayshav you need to be doing research, breaking this problem down, and showing us what you've tried as well. Edit your question and keep editing it as your proceed. You've made a big request, and we are not a free script writing service.